# Can I record 2 things in an Array List in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, class, arraylist

For my homework I had to create a program in C# which has a class called "patient", as so:

```
class patient
{
    private string name;
    private int age;
    private double weight;
    private double height;

    public patient()
    {
        name = "";
        age = 0;
        weight = 0;
        height = 0;
    }

    public patient(string newName, int newAge, double newWeight, double newHeight)
    {
        name = newName;
        age = newAge;
        weight = newWeight;
        height = newHeight;
    }

    public double bmi()
    {
        return weight / Math.Pow(height, 2);
    }

    public bool obese()
    {
        if (bmi() > 27 && age < 40)
            return true;
        else if (bmi() > 30 && age >= 40)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void printDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name);
        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + age);
        Console.WriteLine("Weight: " + weight + "kg");
        Console.WriteLine("Height: " + height + "m");
        Console.WriteLine("BMI: " + bmi());
        if (obese())
            Console.WriteLine("Patient is obese");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Patient is not obese.");
    }
```

And the last part of the question says:
Write a method which records recent patients entered along with their obesity diagnosis into an ArrayList. It should record the five most recent entries and their diagnosis.

Array lists cannot be multi-dimensional, but the question is looking me to record both the obesity diagnosis and the actual patient.

I had thought about storing the object in the array list, but I'm not sure if that is what the question wants.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you ask your teacher/TA? That's very unclear.

Comment: Is there a source list? Is there a source somewhere which contains ALL the patients from which you have to select your patients which meet the criteria?

Comment: You could store their obesity diagnosis in the patient object itself

Answer (score 2):

I would do following:

```
// you will have a history of Records
// a Record contains the Patient + obesity result
public class Record 
{
   public Patient Patient {get; private set;} 
   public bool ObesityResult {get; private set; }
   public Record(Patient patient, bool obesityResult) 
   {
       this.Patient = patient; 
       this.ObesityResult = obesityResult; // save the obese result
   }
}


// now this class will handle the history.
public class RecordHistory 
{
    private ArrayList history; 

    public void Add(Patient patient) 
    { 
        var record = new Record(patient, patient.obese());  // pass the obesity result
        history.Add(patient);  // DO some magic here to keep only 5
    }

   public ArrayList GetHistory() 
   {
      return history;
   }
}
```

Don't take it for a how you should do in real-life example. It's just a homework exercise.